# For bachelors and bachelorettes, is 8 hearts or 10 hearts considered "maxed-out friendship levels"?

Tags: stardew-valley

Version 1.07 introduced a change where friendship levels that have been "maxed-out" no longer decay. For the marriage-eligible villagers, the last two hearts are disabled until you give them a bouquet. Do you need to give each of them a bouquet and then get them to 10 hearts or is 8 hearts and no bouquet sufficient to prevent friendship from decaying?

I'm guessing that since your spouse doesn't like you giving gifts to the marriage-eligible candidates after you're married, you'd have to get those villagers to 10 hearts before you're married, if the decay didn't stop at 10 hearts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

8 hearts friendships with no bouquet will not decay. [ConcernedApe's tweet confirming it](https://twitter.com/ConcernedApe/status/717125346496090112).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, getting to 8 hearts with any marriage candidate will stop the friendship decaying. If you then gave them a bouquet, unlocking the next two hearts, it would start decaying again. Getting them to ten hearts would then stop it decaying once more, all of which can be done with every candidate prior to marrying one of them without any jeolousy penalties.

What is worth pointing out is that the decay is tiny. Talking to them each day gets you 20 friendship points, the decay is 2 points, so just talking to everyone at festivals would be enough to prevent the decay mattering, and actually increase freindship very slightly.

Ref http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Friendship